# как удалить более 2х переносов строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения выводить текст из бд и при этом везде, где более 2х переносов строк подряд, остальные переносы после 2х удалять?
Вот как тут - нажму я 10 раз подряд Enter, всё равно текст выведется вот так:

Всего лишь 1 пустая строка.

Comment: Значит, ответ для PHP принимается? Тогда всё ещё проще - `preg_replace('~(\R)+~', '$1', $input);`, ну, или  `preg_replace('~\R{2,}~', '<br />', $input);`.

Comment: Под "переносом" вы подразумеваете переход на новую строку? Тогда может быть лучше сформулировать так "должно быть не более одной пустой строки подряд". Ещё интересует что у вас используется в качестве разделителя строк? "\n" , "\r\n" или "<br>"?

Answer (score 3):

Для текста (не для HTML) можно воспользоваться заменой (вариант php)

```
$str = preg_replace('%((?:\r\n|\r|\n){2})[\r\n]+%', '$1', $str);
```

Пример тут https://regex101.com/r/sR2iT9/1

P.S. В регулярке указаны три варианта окончания строк: `\r\n`, `\r` и `\n`